# Make a segmented control change the value for another VC

Tags: ios, swift, controls

I have a segmented control, that change some calculations. 
When I had the control in the same VC as the rest of the app, it works, but I want to make a "settings page".

How can I make the selected state of the segmented control in "settingsVC" effect the "mainVC"?

From the "mainVC"

```
// Metric or imperial system segmented control 

    let argumentForSegment = metricImperialSegment.selectedSegmentIndex

    if argumentForSegment == 0 {
        statusLabel.text = "\(kmtLabel)"
        topSpeedLabel.text = "\(topSpeedForLabel) kmh"
        averageSpeedLabel.text = "\(averageSpeedForLabel) kmh"
        altitudeLabel.text = "\(altitudeNoDecimals) m"
        kmhMphLabel.text = "KMH"
    }

    if argumentForSegment == 1 {
        statusLabel.text = "\(mphForLabel)"
```

From the "settingsVC"

```
import UIKit

let argumentForSegment = metricImperialSegment 

class settingsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var metricImperialSegment: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainView", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: post the notification from setting VC to main VC

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to of that?

Comment: You can also make a settingsVC protocol and delegate it to your mainVC. This way, if there is more than settings action effecting your mainVC you can add a function to handle each action individually. I added a gist with an example since I can't add an answer https://gist.github.com/mmr118/3fc87f2bf542892863e8f1c04d92f429